# (Embedded) Raven Studio and my existing MVC 4 routing not working together?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ravendb

I'm new to RavenDB and the embeddable stuff. I searched on Google for almost two hours now, but can't find the solution for my problem; probably because I'm still a RavenDB n00b :-)

My init of the document store looks like this and works fine (I can query for documents):

```
IocContainer.Instance.RegisterSingle(() =>
{
    var ds = new EmbeddableDocumentStore {DataDirectory = "Data", UseEmbeddedHttpServer = true};
    return
        ds
            .Initialize()
            .OpenSession();
});
```

At the first one or two requests the routing is working like I expect it to, so I end up at my HomeController. After another refresh I end up at `/raven/studio.html?...` Great! But not where I expected to land!

If I then change the URL to /Home, like my controller, I see this result:

```
Could not figure out what to do
Your request didn't match anything that Raven knows to do, sorry...
```

Of course, when I remove the `UseEmbeddedHttpServer` it works like it did before but that is not what I want. I want to be able to browse the documents.

My default MVC generated `RouteConfig` with the * added to {id}:

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{*id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turn off the internal Http-server in RavenDb or map the RavenDb-http-server to another port

1:

```
var ds = new EmbeddableDocumentStore {
   DataDirectory = [DataFolder],
  UseEmbeddedHttpServer = false
};
```

2:

```
int ravenPort = 8181;
NonAdminHttp.EnsureCanListenToWhenInNonAdminContext(ravenPort);
var ds = new EmbeddableDocumentStore {
   DataDirectory = [DataFolder],
   UseEmbeddedHttpServer = true,
   Configuration = {Port = ravenPort}
};
```

In case 2 Raven Studio is now reachable on port 8181 instead of being mapped to the port (80) of your website